# How to customize top header links in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

Hello guys i am working with magento 2.1.3 and i want to customize the top header links of my magento ecommerce store. Anybody help this poor guy.
[image]

Comment: https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-1-x-manage-top-header-links/

Comment: What do you want exactly? add new links ? remove links ? update titles ?

Comment: i want to add a new link and change CREATE AN ACCOUNT with Register